# Google's oauth endpoint is returning a 'Bad Request'... but why?

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, httpsurlconnection

After a lot of time wasted googling for the possible reasons for a 'Bad Request' when requesting for a token at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token, I decided to ask why this code can't obtain nothing but a 'bad request' response from the server...

```
String url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Host", "accounts.google.com");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
con.setRequestProperty("code", authCode);
con.setRequestProperty("client_id",
        "[CLIENT_ID]");
con.setRequestProperty("client_secret", "[CLIENT_SECRET");
con.setRequestProperty("redirect_uri",
        "http://localhost:8080/login");
con.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "authorization_code");

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
```

I did have to set `con.setChunkedStreamingMode(0)` because the server was returning an error related to content length.

Any ideas?
Could it be necessary to put the payload in a single line? how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason for the HTTP 400 (Bad Request) is you are sending `code`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `grant_type`, and `redirect_uri` as HTTP request headers where you need to be sending them as query parameters in the body of the HTTP POST request (according to the [Google OAuth2InstalledApp docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp)).

Take a look at [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) for a good example of how to send the HTTP POST. You'll need to take `code`, `client_id`, etc. and write them as a query string in the body:

```
// partial example only: only code and client_id are included
String query = String.format("code=%s&client_id=%s", code, client_id);  
OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();
out.write(query.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

From the Google OAuth2 documentation, a sample HTTP POST request might look something like this:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/v6xr77ewYqhvHSyW6UJ1w7jKwAzu&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

Comment: I think you are correct. Umm I have another question... only the specific oauth properties have to be referenced on that query string? or do I have to set also the content-type there?

Comment: Just the query string parameters. Content-Type needs to be set as a HTTP header. I've updated my answer to show the sample HTTP POST from the Google documentation.